# Is there a way to set thread stack size using GCD?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, recursion, grand-central-dispatch

I have a multiplatform code that has some recursive calls (running in a thread, not the main one), and in some cases the default stack size is not enough for the recursivity depth. I solve this in windows using the /STACK compiler flag:

/STACK:2097152 (2MB, default: 1MB)

But in OSX I use GCD. I readed that it is implemented over pthreads, but I am not able to find a way to set the threads' stack size like pthreads does (using something like pthread_attr_setstacksize).

I tried using the linker flag -Wl,-stack_size -Wl,1000000, but it doesn't matter what amount I set here, my application always crashes at the same recursivity depth level. It seems that this only affects to the main thread, not the ones created after by GCD.

I tried setting the system stack size throught ulimit -s 32768 (default: 8192), it does not affect to the recursivity depth level I can achieve either.

Comment: You don't own the threads GCD uses, so you don't get any control over them. If you need this level of control, you should use threads you create yourself using APIs like pthreads directly.

Comment: OK, it seems that I have no option, I changed my code to use pthreads directly, problem solved. Thanks!